# Drupal. Mobile site detection/redirection suggestions. (Not WURFL or DeviceAtlas)

Tags: mobile, redirect, wurfl

Just looking for some mobile detection advice.

I have used Drupal to develop my site. I am having problems as how to build in mobile detection.

Example: (If on a mobile).

`www.mysite.com` redirects to `m.mysite.com`.
`www.mysite.com/bob` redirects to `m.mysite.com/bob`.

I have heard good things about WURFL but that now requires a fairly expensive license. A quick google got me to DeviceAtlas, but this needs a commercial license also.

Is there no good/open source code out there?

Comment: You will need to accept answers if you want members to take interest in answering your queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScientiaMobile (WURFL) will have a cloud product launching shortly that will have a free version depending on your site traffic, as well as some more affordable plans if purchasing a commercial license isn't a good fit for you.  Might be a fit for your needs when it's available.

Chad

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an alternative to expensive server side detection and redirection service, [handset detection](http://www.handsetdetection.com) can help you with that. The features are one of the best in the industry and it's definitely worth it. They do offer three different plans but the good thing is they offer a free plan and depending on your site traffic, you can just upgrade when you it's necessary.

I hope this helps.

Cheers,

Florante

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check user agent of the browser when a request is received. That contains enough information. Maximum traffic can be expected from iPhone/iPad browsers.

[Here](http://graphicmaniacs.com/note/detecting-iphone-ipod-ipad-android-and-blackberry-browser-with-javascript-and-php/) is an article that lists out the user agent strings

Comment: But that probably doesnt cover 99% of mobiles like wurfl and deviceatlas?

Comment: If your commercial interests dictate that you must cater to 99% mobile devices, then yes, you will need to pay for it; no free lunch. But if you are fine with catering to popular and growing platforms, you could use my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You might like a take a look at 51Degrees.mobi. There is an entirely free for commercial use, no cloud service, version licensed under the Mozilla Public License. If you need more device properties than IsMobile and Screen Size there is a paid for commercial version. For more details see this [link](http://51degrees.mobi/Products/DeviceData.aspx).

James - Founder - 51degrees.mobi